# Python can't import my package

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure:

```
myapp
├── a
│   ├── amodule.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── b
│   ├── bmodule.py
│   ├── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

In `a/amodule.py`
 I have this snippet which calls a simple function in `b/bmodule.py`

```
from  myapp.b import bmodule

b.myfunc()
```

But when i run `python a/amodule.py` I get this error:

```
 File "a/amodule.py", line 1, in <module>
    from  myapp.b import bmodule
ImportError: No module named 'myapp'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this running on 2.x or 3.x?  If the former, did you do `from __future__ import absolute_import`?

Comment: You don't need `myapp`, try `from b.bmodule import myfunc()`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: That's the wrong solution for 3.x (and 2.x if using absolute imports).

Comment: @Kevin: no, that's still the right solution. Look at the traceback. `a` is a top-level package.

Comment: @Martijn: What happens when someone sane tries `python -m myapp.a.amodule`, then?

Comment: @Kevin: The best solution here is to make sure you have your top-level module sorted out, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put your project root onto your python path

you can set the PYTHONPATH environmental variable

or you can alter `sys.path` before importing

or you can use an IDE like pycharm that will do this kind of thing for you

(although it will probably be `from b import blah`)

there is likely other ways to resolve this issue as well

watch out for circular imports ...

(in python 3 you can also do relative imports... although I am not a big fan of this feature)

```
from ..b import blah
```

the best way to allow

```
from myapp.b import whatever
```

would be to edit your `.bashrc` file to always add your parent path to the PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH;/home/lee/Code
```

now every time you log into the system python will treat your `Code` folder as a default place to look for import modules, regardless of where the file is executed from

Comment: I wouldn't recommend fiddling with `sys.path`.  Either have your top-level script at the same level as the `myapp` directory, or install the package in a directory Python searches by default, or use `PYTHONPATH`.  This is an environment setting and it should be dealt wiith outside of the Python code.

Comment: I agree its not an ideal solution... but it is a solution that would resolve the issue (and I agree that its an environment issue, not a project structure issue nor a code issue)

Comment: I set my python path to ```/home/lee/Code/myapp
``` and i still get the same error

Comment: @SvenMarnach how would I put the package in a directory python searches by default?

Comment: no set it to the parent ... `export PYTHONPATH=/home/lee/Code;python myapp.py` @JohnDoe you *can* put it in the `lib\pythonxx\site-packages` folder ... but you really shouldnt ... instead add `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH;/home/lee/Code` to your `/home/lee/.bashrc` file

Comment: @JohnDoe I would really recommend using a better IDE (maybe pycharm)